# Create PowerShell Cmdlets in C# - Pipeline chaining

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I have some classes in C# which I would like to use them in pipelines, I've seen articles about it but I haven't been able to do it yet.

Here's how I am using it right now:

```
$suite = [MyProject.SuiteBuilder]::CreateSuite('my house')

$houseSet = $suite.AddSet('doors', 'These represents doors')
$houseSet.AddOption('blue', 'kitchen')
$houseSet.AddOption('black', 'bedreoom')
$houseSet.AddOption('white', 'toilet')
```

And I want to be able to use it like this with pipelines:

```
$suite = [MyProject.SuiteBuilder]::CreateSuite('my house')

$suite | AddSet('doors', 'These represents doors') `
       | AddOption('blue', 'kitchen') `
       | AddOption('black', 'bedreoom') `
       | AddOption('white', 'toilet')
```

Here are my C# classes:

```
//SuiteBuilder.cs
public static class SuiteBuilder
{
    public static Suite CreateTestSuite(string name)
    {
        return new Suite(name);
    }
}

//Suite.cs
public class Suite : PSCmdlet
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Set> Sets { get; set; }

    public Suite(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
        Sets = new List<Set>();
    }

    // call this method in pipeline
    public Set AddSet(string type, string description)
    {
        Sets.Add(new Set(type, description));
        return Sets.Last();
    }
}


//Set.cs
public class Set : PSCmdlet
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Option> Options { get; set; }

    public Set(string type, string description)
    {
        Type = type;
        Description = description;
        Options = new List<Option>();
    }

    // call this method from pipeline
    public Set AddOption(string color, string place)
    {
        Options.Add(new Option(color, place));
        return this;
    }
}


//option.cs
public class Option : PSCmdlet
{
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public string Place { get; set; }

    public Option(string color, string place)
    {
        Color = color;
        Place = place;
    }
}
```

And I am struggling to make these function available to call in the pipeline form.

I also added a comment like `call this method in pipeline`  before each comment that I need to call.

Comment: Why pipelines? Wouldn't (sorry, I can't put newlines in comments, please proceed to imagine them) `$houseSet = $suite.AddSet('doors', 'These represents doors').AddOption('blue', 'kitchen').AddOption('black', 'bedreoom').AddOption('white', 'toilet')` be enough? It's a noncomplex compromise that should work on your code without even making changes to it.

Comment: @ensisNoctis yep, but its just that pipelines looks much clearer

Comment: It says [here](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/net-development/using-c-to-create-powershell-cmdlets-the-basics/#tenth) you need to decorate the parameters with a  System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute like `[Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = true)]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, you need to:

- Accept parameter from pipeline by using `[Parameter(ValueFromPipeline =true)]`
- Provide output to pipeline by calling `WriteObject` method in process method

### Detailed Step by Step answer

In this post I'll refactor your code a bit and will show you how you can create [Powershell Cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/cmdlet-overview?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=powershell-6) in C# and how to **define parameters**, **accept parameter from pipeline** and **provide output to pipeline**. Then you can easily write something like:

```js
$suite = [MyCmdLets.Suite]::New("suite1")
$suite | Add-Set "type1" "desc1"`
       | Add-Option "color1" "place1"`
       | Add-Option "color2" "place2" | Out-Null
```

To do so, follow these steps:

1. Create a C# class Library Project (for example name it `MyCmdlets`)
2. Install Package [`Microsoft.PowerShell.5.ReferenceAssemblies`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.PowerShell.5.ReferenceAssemblies/)
3. Create your model classes, independent from PowerShell. (See the code at the bottom of post)
4. Create the cmdlets considering the following notes: (See the code at the bottom of post)

   - Per each cmdlet, create a C# class
   - Derive from [`Cmdlet`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.cmdlet?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=pscore-6.2.0) class
   - Decorate the class with [`CmdletAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.cmdletattribute?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=pscore-6.2.0) attribute specifying the verb and the name after verb, for example if you want to have `Add-Set`, use `[Cmdlet(VerbsCommon.Add, "Set")]`.
   - If you want to have an output for pipeline, decorate the class with [`OutputTypeAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.outputtypeattribute?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=pscore-6.2.0) attribute specifying the type of output, for example if you want to have an output of type `Set` for the pipeline, use `[OutputType(typeof(Set))]`.
   - Per each input parameter of your cmdlet, define a C# property.
   - Decorate each parameter property by `Parameter` attribute.
   - If you want to accept a parameter from pipeline, when decorating with [`ParameterAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.parameterattribute?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=pscore-6.2.0) attribute, set [`ValueFromPipeline`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.parameterattribute.valuefrompipeline?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=pscore-6.2.0) to true, fro example `[Parameter(ValueFromPipeline =true)`
   - To provide output to pipeline, override pipeline processing methods like [`ProcessRecord`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.cmdlet.processrecord?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=pscore-6.2.0) and using [`WriteObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.cmdlet.writeobject?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=pscore-6.2.0) write the to output.
5. Build the project.
6. Open PowerShell ISE and run the following code:

   ```
   Import-Module "PATH TO YOUR BIN DEBUG FOLDER\MyCmdlets.dll"

   $suite = [MyCmdLets.Suite]::New("suite1")
   $suite | Add-Set "type1" "desc1"`
          | Add-Option "color1" "place1"`
          | Add-Option "color2" "place2" | Out-Null
   ```

   It will create a structure like this:

   ```
   Name   Sets           
   ----   ----           
   suite1 {MyCmdlets.Set}


   Type  Description Options                             
   ----  ----------- -------                             
   type1 desc1       {MyCmdlets.Option, MyCmdlets.Option}


   Color  Place 
   -----  ----- 
   color1 place1
   color2 place2
   ```

### Sample Code

**Model Classes**

As mentioned above, design your model classes independent from PowerShell like this:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace MyCmdlets
{
    public class Suite
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Set> Sets { get; } = new List<Set>();
        public Suite(string name) {
            Name = name;
        }
    }
    public class Set
    {
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public List<Option> Options { get; } = new List<Option>();
        public Set(string type, string description) {
            Type = type;
            Description = description;
        }
    }
    public class Option 
    {
        public string Color { get; set; }
        public string Place { get; set; }
        public Option(string color, string place) {
            Color = color;
            Place = place;
        }
    }
}
```

**CmdLet Classes**

Also design the cmdlet classes based on notes which I describe above:

```
using System.Management.Automation;
namespace MyCmdlets
{
    [Cmdlet(VerbsCommon.Add, "Set"), OutputType(typeof(Set))]
    public class AddSetCmdlet : Cmdlet
    {
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = true, Mandatory = true)]
        public Suite Suite { get; set; }
        [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory = true)]
        public string Type { get; set; }
        [Parameter(Position = 1, Mandatory = true)]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        protected override void ProcessRecord() {
            var set = new Set(Type, Description);
            Suite.Sets.Add(set);
            WriteObject(set);
        }
    }

    [Cmdlet(VerbsCommon.Add, "Option"), OutputType(typeof(Option))]
    public class AddOptionCmdlet : Cmdlet
    {
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = true, Mandatory = true)]
        public Set Set { get; set; }
        [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory = true)]
        public string Color { get; set; }
        [Parameter(Position = 1, Mandatory = true)]
        public string Place { get; set; }
        protected override void ProcessRecord() {
            var option = new Option(Color, Place);
            Set.Options.Add(option);
            WriteObject(Set);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ValueFromPipeline = $true. However, you will have to reference the type variable, and return the item if you want to continue the pipeline. I don't know of a way to work around this. Since it will return, you would have to add an `Out-Null` at the end to prevent it from hitting console.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_ref?view=powershell-6

```
function Add-Option {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
        [ref]$Item,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
        [String]$Color
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 1)]
        [String]$Room
    )
    $Item.Value.AddOption($Color,$Room)
    return $Item
}

$suite = [MyProject.SuiteBuilder]::CreateSuite('my house')

[ref]$suite | Add-Option 'blue' 'kitchen' `
            | Add-Option 'black' 'bedroom' `
            | Out-Null
```

Comment: Note: I changed AddOption to Add-Option for proper schema, but you could use AddOption if you wanted to.